# Check if HTML5 audio was already playing when clicking to change source?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have a WIP HTML5 audio player that can switch between any of 20 files.

I'm trying to make it so:

- If the audio was playing, it auto plays after switching source
- If the audio was not playing, it only loads metadata

So far the only way I can do it is by checking if the play/pause image src is currently pointing to the pause image. I don't want this attached to an src that can easily change or even not be an image later.

If I check for audioPlayer.paused it evaluates to true and begins autoplaying if the audio was paused before clicking, but checking for false doesn't work at all.

I've tried the audio events 'playing' and 'progress' when clicking to change source but they don't work. The time updates, but it doesn't begin playing and the if statement doesn't fire at all.

I've included both if statements !paused and .playing just to show how it was done. Only one is used in the code.

```
var audioPlayer = $("#main-audio-player").get(0);
$(".artist-row").click(function(){

    var songUrl = $(this).data("surl");
    var artistName = $(this).data("artist-name");
    var songName = $(this).data("song-name");
    var artistImage = $(this).data("artist-image");

    $("#main-audio-player").attr("src", songUrl);
    $("#artist-span").text(artistName);
    $("#song-span").text(songName);
    $("#artist-image").attr("src", artistImage);

    // Doesn't work
    if (audioPlayer.playing) {
      audioPlayer.play();
    } else {
      audioPlayer.load();
    }

    // Also doesn't work?
    if (!audioPlayer.paused) {
      audioPlayer.play();
    } else {
      audioPlayer.load();
    }
```

});